# problema con el server de ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

hola amigos tengo instalado ruby y ruby  on rails y funciona correctame pero
el servidor no funciona con el comando "rails server" sino con "gem server"

mensaje del error:

```
    root@sommer0123-AO532h:/home/sommer0123/Escritorio/blogruby/blog# rails server
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/sommer0123/Escritorio/blogruby/blog/config/boot.rb:3:in `'
    from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
    from bin/rails:3:in `'
root@sommer0123-AO532h:/home/sommer0123/Escritorio/blogruby/blog# gem server
Server started at http://0.0.0.0:8808
Server started at http://[::]:8808
```

mi duda es habria algun problema con la app web en produccion?

nota uso:ubuntu escritorio 16.2 tls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a ejecutar en la terminal:

```
bundle install
```

Puede que haya fallado al ejecutarlo por primera vez o que lo ejecutases con sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con

```
bundle exec rails s
```

Comment: Sería posible que explicas porque es es la solución? Las respuestas no son solamente para aliviar la vida del OP, pero también para gente que buscan informaciones sobre problemas parecidos en el futuro.

Comment: OP? Explicate??

Comment: OP se refiere a "Original Poster"